# Entity Framework Error: Specified Include Path Is Not Valid for Virtual Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I am encountering an error to the effect of "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'MyCMS.DAL.SiteSettings' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'SiteSettingOptions'."

I have read quite a few posts about this issue but all of the research I have done pertains to ICollections and not for properties that are classes.

Here is where I am and could use your help resolving the issues.

```
[Table("SiteSettingsBridge")]
[DataContract]
public partial class SiteSettings
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int SiteSettingsBridgeID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int SiteID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int SiteSettingOptionID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual SiteSettingOptions SiteSettingOption { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public SiteSettings()
    {
        SiteSettingsBridgeID = 0;
        SiteID = 0;
        SiteSettingOptionID = 0;
        Value = "";
    }
}



[DataContract]
public partial class SiteSettingOptions
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int SiteSettingOptionID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string SettingsGroup { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SettingType Type { get; set; }

    public enum SettingType
    {
        String = 1,
        Bool = 2,
        Integer = 3
    }

    public SiteSettingOptions()
    {
        SiteSettingOptionID = 0;
        SettingsGroup = string.Empty;
        Name = string.Empty;
        DefaultValue = string.Empty;
        Type = SiteSettingOptions.SettingType.String;
    }
}
```

and then in my DAL project, I am attempting to add an Include to the context query like this

```
public static List<Contracts.Sites.SiteSettings> GetBySiteID(int SiteID)
{
 using (CMSContext cntx = new CMSContext())
 {
    ///OMITTED FOR BREVITY

    return cntx.SiteSettings.Include("SiteSettingOptions").Where(i => i.SiteID == SiteID).ToList();

 }
}
```

When I compile and run, I am receiving the above error.

To answer a few questions up front, I am not using LazyLoading and I am not doing anything on model create.

Yes, I am brand new to EF. This is my first app.

Comment: Your property is called `SiteSettingOption` (no s) but you are trying to `Include("SiteSettingOptions")` (notice the final s). Remove the last s. You can avoid this by using the Include extension that uses lambdas rather than strings this would be something like `Include(x => x.SiteSettingOption)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was mistakenly under the impression that the string inside of the quotes was pointing to a table in the database. As a side note, I cannot use the lambda anywhere in the DAL project. I am not sure why. I get a compile error of "Cannot convert lambda expression to type string". I have seen this posted everywhere but it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: For whatever reason the lambda based `Include` is an extension method in a different class in a different namespace. You need to add `using System.Data.Entity` to be able to use it.

Comment: Ben...you rock! Thank's again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ben...

Your property is called SiteSettingOption (no s) but you are trying to `Include("SiteSettingOptions")` (notice the final s). Remove the last s. You can avoid this by using the Include extension that uses lambdas rather than strings this would be something like `Include(x => x.SiteSettingOption)`